# PyQGIS - problem with launching the print layout

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I would like to open the QGIS Print layout by using Python.

I found some hints here:

[QgsPrintLayout Setup from PyQGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277223/qgsprintlayout-setup-from-pyqgis-3)
[PyQGIS - Managing print layouts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311390/pyqgis-managing-print-layouts)

and here:

https://data.library.virginia.edu/how-to-create-and-export-print-layouts-in-python-for-qgis-3/

but unfortunately everywhere is the same problem. I am getting an error:

**IndentationError: unexpected indent**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920628/indentationerror-unexpected-indent-error

and I don't really know how to solve it

My simple code looks like this:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()         
manager = project.layoutManager()       
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)        
layoutName = "Strand_012"

#initializes default settings for blank print layout canvas
layout.initializeDefaults()  

layout.setname(layoutName)
manager.addLayout(layout)

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
map.setExtent(canvas.extent())
layout.addLayoutItem(map)
```

I would like to open my map canvas in print layout and export it as PNG setting 170 Dpi resolution for it.
How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove the leading spaces in each line.

[image]

Comment: It looks like I am on the right track, but now I have an error:
AttributeError: 'QgsPrintLayout' object has no attribute 'setname'

Comment: it would be `setName` (capital N).

Comment: I have nowhere setName in my code

Comment: Replace `layout.setname(layoutName)` (present in your code) with `layout.setName(layoutName)` You made a typo hence @MirandaKwon suggestion